# FPDF/FPDI and Microsoft Internet Explorer and Edge

Tags: php, internet-explorer, fpdf, microsoft-edge

I am currently utilising FPDF for the first time and everything works great so far in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Mobile Chrome, Mobile Safari but both Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge give me issues.

I have a page where a user can fill in a form with their own company name and adress information.
They are also required to upload their company logo.

I use **FPDF** combined with **FPDI** for the use of templates/PDFs
Our designers made the PDF in InDesign and that is all good.
I start by declaring a new FPDI and importing in the base PDF (it has 8 pages) as the first source and template.

The first 5 pages in the PDF are as followed

- Cover 1
- Cover 2
- Cover 3
- Cover 4
- Cover 5

In my HTML form I have a select input where the user can choose between the five.
Which I then pick up in PHP and load the correct page as follow:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('../pdf/source-brochure.pdf');
// Add the Cover
$tplCover = $pdf->importPage($cover_versie, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplCover, 0, 0, 210);
$pdf->Image($newFile, $baseOffsetX, $baseOffsetY);

$cover_versie; // Outputs the integer 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 for the covers
$newFile; // Is the uploaded logo resised and uploaded to the server
```

The logo is resized and edited through a [php script](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php)

Now the 5th option is a custom cover where the user can upload their own cover image to the form (this input field is shown when Cover 5 is chosen)

So in my Switch Statement where I check which cover the user has chosen I have this following code:

```
if ($custimg->uploaded) {
    $custimg->image_resize              = true;
    $custimg->image_x                   = 741;
    $custimg->image_y                   = 792;
    $custimg->image_ratio               = true;
    $custimg->image_ratio_fill          = true;
    $custimg->image_ratio_crop          = 'TL';
    $custimg->image_ratio_no_zoom_in    = false;
    $custimg->image_ratio_no_zoom_out   = false;
    $custimg->image_convert             = 'png';
    $custimg->process('uploads/');
    if ($custimg->processed) {
        $customcoverimage = $custimg->file_dst_pathname;
        $custimg->clean();
    }
}
```

The rest of the form is not required and fall back using ternary operators like so:

```
$filename = (!empty($companyname)) ? $companyname : time();
```

So after the cover is chosen and done I add the 6th page from the source PDF which is a Spread page and requires no edits so I import that as the new page:

```
// Add the content of the brochure
$tplContent = $pdf->importPage(6, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage('L', 'A4');
$pdf->useTemplate($tplContent, 0, 0, 297);
```

Alright nothing too hard here.

Next up is the last page.
For this I also have a input select option in my form.
There are 2 flavors to choose from.

```
// Add the Back
$tplBack = $pdf->importPage($achter_versie, '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplBack, 0, 0, 210);

$achter_versie; // Outputs the integer 7 or 8 based on the chosen back
```

Now here we get a little tricky.
On the last page there is a spot where I need to loop through 5 checkboxes in the form to see which sponsors the company uses and output their respective logo's next to eachother:

So I first count the amount of checkboxes are checked.
I get the values of the checkboxes in a loop and through a for loop I add the logo's (which are uploaded to a default folder) to the page:

```
// Get the checkbox values
            if ($nrofkeurmerken != 1) {
                for ($x1 = 0; $x1 <= $nrofkeurmerken-1; $x1++) {
                    $brandBaseX = 10;
                    $baseImgWidth = 29.897916667;

                    if ($keurmerken[$x1] != 'eigen') {
                        $keurmerkname[] = "../img/keurmerken/logo-" . $keurmerken[$x1] . ".png";

                        $pdf->Image($keurmerkname[$x1], $brandBaseX + ($baseImgWidth * $x1) + 5, 270);
                    } else {
                        $keurimg = new upload($_FILES['keurmerkfile']);
                        if ($keurimg->uploaded) {
                            $keurimg->image_resize              = true;
                            $keurimg->image_x                   = 113;
                            $keurimg->image_y                   = 71;
                            $keurimg->image_ratio               = true;
                            $keurimg->image_ratio_no_zoom_in    = true;
                            $keurimg->image_ratio_no_zoom_out   = false;
                            $keurimg->image_convert             = 'png';
                            $keurimg->process('uploads/');
                            if ($keurimg->processed) {
                                $customkeurmerkimage = $keurimg->file_dst_pathname;

                                $pdf->Image($customkeurmerkimage, $brandBaseX + ($baseImgWidth * $x1) + 5, 270);

                                $keurimg->clean();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ($nrofkeurmerken == 1) {
                $brandBaseX = 10;
                $baseImgWidth = 29.897916667;
                $keurmerkname = "../img/keurmerken/logo-snf.png";   
                $pdf->Image($keurmerkname, $brandBaseX + ($baseImgWidth * 0) + 5, 270);
            }
```

Now In All modern browsers (except IE11 and MS Edge) this works.

But both IE11 and Edge have the error that the PDF does not start with %PDF
At first my error was incorrect type of file but I added the

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

which solved that problem.

If anyone understands this that would be awesome haha.
Thanks for the time to look though!

Comment: *Removed for incomplete*

Comment: The `header()` call is normally not needed as this is done by FPDF in its `Output()` method. You may try to play with the Output-parameter. Turn it to "D" to force a download of the document. If you can reproduce the issue with that file, please share it, so that we can take a deeper look. I guess you're simply sending something to the client which is not related to the PDF.

Comment: Forcing it to download is not helping in IE11 it opens a tab but "hangs" then when I hit the submit button with that tab still open it finally generates.

Comment: Here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/RPSource/e182d9234aef131f3251

Comment: Remove the header() call at the top, it will be send by FPDF, automatically. If you receive a file and if you're unable to open it, please share it!

Comment: Thank you for replying :)
Here is a PDF that is succesfully downloaded through chrome but fails in IE and Edge. https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8osn614zvj7u69/brochure_test.pdf?dl=0

I get the feeling it has to do with the image upload/resize class

Comment: Could you show a resulting file that fails in IE/Edge? The linked file works in Edge without problems.

Comment: Sadly no cause Edge and IE don't output anything but weirdly enough this problem is something far different I notice now after 6 hours debugging.

Both Edge and IE can't do anything because the "$_FILES" array always returns empty.

I have a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" yet the page always returns "Undefined index"

This is the current code I try: https://gist.github.com/RPSource/f094115ee97a1fd9e8c1

And it returns absolutely nothing

Comment: What would it output if you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script? And what is your html? Maybe you should create a very simple POC which will allow you to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Setasign THANK YOU! I think it had to do with the html form even though I visually still can't see the difference but I rewrote a big part of the HTML and also rewrote the whole PHP but the $_FILES did return something after a html restructure. I must've made a mistake somewhere and I still need to find it but it works perfectly right now. Thank you for the help and the great FPDI class many MANY thanks

Comment: and nevermind... It still does not work for our client and our local machines (I tested it on a IE11 Virtual machine and a laptop with IE10 (win7)) worked fine... I am so confused right now... I guessed it was the Acrobar Reader plugin maybe but I'm forcing a download using the 'D' option. So what the hell is going on.

Comment: It seems like it works in "some" Internet Explorer 11 browsers but It will not force a download or show the PDF in the browser.
It just opens a blank tab and does absolutely nothing.
Even though my error logs do read the $_POST and $_FILES Data.

Comment: You should reduce this to a simple POC and provide code and a link to execute it. Without seeing anything it is impossible to assist.

Comment: Thank you for putting up with me :) I have a poc small version on how I approach. 
IE11: It sees the uploaded filename in the Error_log but does not output it to the PDF 
MS Edge: Does not see the uploaded File and echo's out. error: PHP Notice: Undefined index: userfile in /... on line *

Download POC:
http://we.tl/65TaVQ4s5U

Comment: Use "D" as dest parameter and remove the target-attribute from the form-tag. It really looks like a strange behaviour of Edge to me. I cannot reproduce this in IE11.

Comment: Thanks that did solve the problem for internet explorer...Edge is a strange issue indeed but I opted for a browser message.